# Given an infinite poset of a certain cardinality, does it contains always a chain or antichain of the same cardinality?

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

It is known that given an infinite poset, it always contains an infinite chain or antichain;
moreover, there is a constructive proof that we can find a continuous chain in $P(\mathbb{N})$;
so, in general, I'm asking if given a poset of a certain cardinality, we could always find a chain or antichain of the same cardinality.

Comment: Maybe off topic. What is a "continuous chain"?

Comment: @Srivatsan, in this case it seems to mean a chain of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: @Srivatsan, yes Henning is right.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In fact, there is a negative answer provable in ZFC.  Since we have choice, well-order the interval $[0,1]$.  Then let $x\sqsubset y$ if and only if the well-order agrees with the standard order of the reals and $x<y$.  Then $[0,1]$ with the ordering $\sqsubset$ is an uncountable poset with neither an uncountable chain nor an uncountable anti-chain.

Consider any uncountable $S\subseteq[0,1]$.  Let $z$ be the infimum of the set $$\{x\in [0,1]|\text{ there are uncountably many }y<x\text{ with }y\in S\}$$  $S$ cannot be a chain since otherwise, a countable increasing sequence of elements of $S$ converging to $z$ would be cofinal in $\omega_1$.

Similarly, we can take $w$ to be the supremum of the set $$\{x\in [0,1]|\text{ there are uncountably many }y>x\text{ with }y\in S\}$$  Then if $S$ was an anti-chain, then a countable decreasing sequence (according to the standard ordering of the reals) in $S$ would again be cofinal in $\omega_1$.

Comment: I don't understand your definition of $x \sqsubset y$: what are $x$ and $y$ here and how do they figure into the rest of the definition?

Comment: Sorry, x and y are taken to be real numbers in [0,1].

Comment: To be clear, in the second and third paragraphs, do all references to order (infimum, $<$, increasing, etc) refer to the order defined in the first paragraph?

Comment: No, they refer to the standard ordering of the reals.

Comment: The answer should now be fixed to make it clear that you could use either ordering.

Comment: Thanks. I was worried for a minute about what to do about the case where the two displayed sets are empty, but I see a way around it. The key point is that $S$, being a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$, is separable in the usual topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: How exactly does being separable fix this?

Comment: @Carl, That's why I restricted to $[0,1]$.  Now 1 is always in the first set and 0 is always in the second.

Comment: @Jason DeVito: Say the first displayed set is empty. By separability take a countable sequence $(s_i)$ in $S$ which is increasing and cofinal in $S$ (so either $(s_i) \to \infty$ or $(s_i) \to \sup S$). Then for each $i$, $\{ x \in S : x < s_i\}$ is countable, and so $S$ is a countable union of countable sets.

Comment: @Carl:  Thanks!  I think I finally understand this beautiful answer.  (I haven't thought about order theory in a few years - this was a wonderful trip back through it.  Thanks!!)

Comment: @Aubrey de Cunha: if $1 \not \in S$? Maybe you meant $x \in [0,1]$, which I think works as well.

Comment: @Carl: You are correct. That is what I meant.  Edited.

Comment: It's perhaps worth mentioning that this clever argument is attributed to Sierpinski.

Answer (score 9):

A [Suslin tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suslin_tree) is a poset (in fact, a tree) that has cardinality $\omega_1$ but every chain and every antichain is countable. The existence of a Suslin tree is neither provable nor disprovable in ZFC. Therefore, your question does not have an affirmitive answer provable in ZFC.

<s>I do not know whether it has a negative answer (using something other than Suslin trees) provable in ZFC.</s> Aubrey da Cunha has given a proof that the answer to the question is "no". That answer should be accepted over this one.

Answer (score 5):

A natural negative answer is to take the poset $\bigcup_{n\in\omega} \{n\}\times\omega_n$, with two points comparable iff their first coordinates coincide. Any antichain here is countable, and any chain has size strictly below $\aleph_\omega$, which is the size of the whole set. Note that this does not use any form of choice.

Answer (score 0):

This is true exactly for $\omega$ and for weakly compact cardinals. It is proved in

> G.D. Badenhorst and T. Sturm, *An order- and graph-theoretical characterisation of weakly compact cardinals*, in Cycles and Rays (NATO Adv. Sci. Inst. Ser. C Math. Phys. Sci., 301), 1990, pp.19-20, [MR1096981](http://ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1096981).

Answer (score 0):

This is the same answer as @aubrey's, but with an alternate proof.

Let $\preceq$ well-order the real numbers $\mathbb R$, and let $\leq$ be the usual ordering of $\mathbb R$. Then $\sqsubseteq$ defined by $x\sqsubseteq y$ if and only if $x\preceq y$ and $x\leq y$ is a partial order of $\mathbb R$.

We claim that every chain and antichain with respect to $\sqsubseteq$ is countable. To see this, let $C=\{c_\alpha:\alpha<|C|\}$ such that $\alpha<\beta$ if and only if $c_\alpha\prec c_\beta$.

We use the following lemma: given any increasing/decreasing sequence of reals, there is an increasing/decreasing sequence of rational numbers of the same cardinality (choose a rational between each term and its successor). Therefore every increasing/decreasing sequence of reals is countable.

If $C$ is a chain, then $\alpha<\beta$ implies $c_\alpha < c_\beta$, since $c_\alpha$ and $c_\beta$ are comparable by $\sqsubseteq$. Since there does not exist an uncountable increasing sequence of reals, $C$ is countable.

If $C$ is an antichain, then $\alpha<\beta$ implies $c_\alpha \not< c_\beta$ (equivalently, $c_\alpha >c_\beta$), since $c_\alpha$ and $c_\beta$ are incomparable by $\sqsubseteq$. Since there does not exist an uncountable decreasing sequence of reals, $C$ is countable.